# Is there a tool to convert from a programming language to another?

Tags: javascript, c#, xaml

Is there a solution [online or app] to convert a programming language to another one?

For example:

- I have XAML code and I want to convert it to javaScript and otherwise.
- I have C# code and I want to convert it to javaScript and otherwise.

Comment: you can't convert all C# in JavaScript so if there would be a tool for that it won't work always.

Comment: Are you aware of the differences between the programming languages you mentioned? They are usually aimed at totally different applications.

Comment: Wow then we would all be flooding careers forum and answering job switching questions

Comment: Don't know which part of "For example" you guys don't understand?

Comment: In the case of Xaml to JavaScript, how deep must the translator go?  If a control in the Xaml took a parameter setting from the static System Parameters class, things could get hairy pretty quick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look at [this project](http://jsc.sourceforge.net/) (claims to do C#>Javascript :) also look at Script# [see video here](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/HTM16)

Comment: The most complete and functional is 
[JSIL](http://jsil.org/) 

Has not fully language support, but it can translate some full games and software.

Answer (score 5):

when doing web development you're able to translate ASP.NET and C# code to JavaScript using Script# http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp

I think you should review the ideas behind each of the languages to get an understanding of their goals.

Comment: The url is death - The requested URL could not be retrieved

Answer (score 4):

In order to convert code both languages must be identical, for example C# to VB.
Converting languages that serve different purposes is not feasible, and the only options are tricky and full of errors.

You can look at this one: http://michaelsync.net/2007/10/29/script-c-to-javascript-converter